# Localization : How to change localised Strings dynamically without giving deployment on Play store

Tags: android, localization

We have implemented our app in three languages
i.e Marathi, English, and Hindi.

But If I wanted to correct any text from the app I have to upload .apk to the play store
So User will get that change.

Is there any way where I can do that dynamically without giving deployment?

And the change will reflect automatically.

Comment: You can make your text strings in application dependent on backend.

Comment: thanks for the reply can you please elaborate on how we can do that?

Comment: What currently we do in our apps that we set strings in strings.xml. Rather than putting strings in that file, retrieve them from your server.

Comment: `Is there any way where I can do that dynamically ` unless you're getting these values from an api or a backend, no